# Updating a nested list using elements from another nested list of the same shape

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica. A quick question:

Given

```
a = {{1,0,0,2},{2,0,1,0}} 
aR = {{1,0,1,0},{0,1,0,1}}
```

if element in `a` is `0`, I would like to replace this element with the element from `aR` in the same position, so results should be `

> `{{1, 0, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 1}}`.

I tried this but does not work

```
(a[[#1, #2]] = If [a[[#1, #2]] == 0, aR[[#2, #1]], a[[#1, #2]]]) & @@@
   {Range[Part[Dimensions[a], 1]], Range[Part[Dimensions[a], 2]]};
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: `a + (1 - Unitize@a)*aR`... and perhaps more understandable `ReplacePart[a, {x_, y_} /; a[[x, y]] == 0 :> aR[[x, y]]]` or `MapThread[If[# == 0, #2, #] &, {a, aR}, 2]`

Comment: `MapIndexed[If[#1 == 0, Extract[aR, #2], #1] &, a, {2}]`

Answer (score 6):

ciao doesn't like to write answers, so I will do it as a CW.

```
a + (1 - Unitize@a)*aR
```

Perhaps more understandable:

```
ReplacePart[a, {x_, y_} /; a[[x, y]] == 0 :> aR[[x, y]]]
```

or

```
MapThread[If[# == 0, #2, #] &, {a, aR}, 2]
```

All give

> `{{1, 0, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1, 1}}`

Comment: Just a note: the first method is about 50 times faster on bigger datasets

Comment: @BlacKow - `a1 + BitXor[1, Unitize@a1]*a2` s/b a bit faster yet...

Comment: @ciao, well, when you put it that way: `{{1, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 1, 0}} ~BitOr~ {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}}`. (Of course, this assumes the entries in the two matrices are all nonnegative integers.)

Comment: @J.M.--- might want to rethink that ;=}